# Automation: Sending sms based on button press in alarm

Tags: automation, alarm

### My Problem:

I want to get a reminder or an alarm every sunday and tuesday evening that gives me the chance to press two buttons: one that sends an sms to another person with content x and another button with to send the sms with content y.
I thought about something like this:

Displayed:

```
IF (Sunday 19:00 or Tuesday 19:00)
   *Show me A Screen (sth. like an alarm) with two buttons
   IF (Button x)
      Send SMS (or better telegram or whatsapp or messenger) with content x to recipient a
   ELSE
      Send SMS with content y to recipient a
```

i already looked into [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/discover) but it doesnt do the thing with the button-decision afaik.

Thanks for *any* help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate&referrer=utm_source%3Dstackoverflow) (free). Use the following blocks:

1. [Time await](http://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/time_await.html)
2. [Dialog choice](http://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/dialog_choice.html)
3. [SMS send](http://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/sms_send.html)